# Limitation on length of bin name in citrusleaf

Tags: nosql, key-value-store

Is there a limitation on length of bin name in citrusleaf.
Is the default value 14 and can it be increased?

I am getting following error if the length of binName is more than 14 characters (using Java API)

null due to parameter error

Answer (score 1):

This restrictions is enforced from server-side.
This is an artificial restriction to keep the memory & disk requirement in control.
Note that this is only for the bin name and not the bin value.

The wire protocol is a generic interface. So, it allows any length to be passed.
Different limits are followed for different names.
For e.g. namespace & set names should be <32 bytes

Answer (score 0):

The bottom line is that you cannot use bin names longer than 14 characters using the current Citrusleaf version